# Triggering Cartthrob shipping options with country select?

Tags: cartthrob

I'm using default CT store template and Shipping by Location Weight Threshold w/Options shipping plugin (https://github.com/CartThrob/cartthrob-shipping-by_location_weight_threshold_w_options) on EE 2.9/CT 2.6, and running into issue on Shipping template where toggling between countries doesn't correctly reset the shipping options select display.

It does generate the correct shipping price for the leftnav display, but the select itself doesn't refresh to show the proper rates. So, if you switch from USA to UK (or any other country), it'll change the leftnav from USA to correct UK shipping amount, but the select still shows the USA options.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using any discounts on shipping? Whats happening in your code here - are you using Ajax or reloading the page on changing a shipping country?

Comment: No discounts. I'm using the plugin pretty straight up, but I did adjust to accommodate the number of options I needed. I have the 5 options pictured for US customers w/orders weighing under 4 lbs. Over 4 lbs has different rate, and fewer options. Canada customers have one rate for under 4, and another rate for over 4. Then the last global tier that has one rate under 4, and one rate over 4.

Comment: The shipping price is applied correctly to the left display via Ajax w/o a reload, but that shipping option select doesn't change accordingly.